# Laravel and Flutter Notifications System

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, flutter, dart

I Want to Build a Web App with Mobile App in one platform. So, Both of Them will use the Same Database which is MySQL.
I want to use Laravel as backend and flutter for mobile app
Also, I want to build notifications system "when the user does something he will get pop up notification"
and that is the problem.
I searched a lot about this but I found nothing.
for Laravel, I can use Pusher and it's pretty easy.
but I didn't found anything to integrate it to flutter.

**NOTE:**

I'm beginner at flutter. But i'm good at laravel.

**UPDATE**

it's okey if there is any other method to do this

Answer (score 0):

For flutter there is package called flutter_local_notifications, 
link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

also there is pusher package 
https://pub.dev/packages/pusher

so you can use these 2 together, so when a user trigger an event with API, a listener will send notification to pusher, so the other user would listen to it using pusher package.

At this moment you got the notification on your mobile using pusher package, only then you can trigger local notification using the other package instantly.